# Animate SVG using <object>

Tags: jquery, html, css, svg

I am trying to animate a large SVG using CSS.

When I put the SVG directly in the HTML it works fine.

When I try to use `<object>` it loads the SVG letter by letter and the CSS classes are not captured. The goal is to have the SVG in a file and include it in the HTML.

HTML 
`<object id="svg" data="img/logo.svg" type="image/svg+xml"></object>`

When I inspect the DOM, the all the SVG code is included correctly (the `<object>` expands into the SVG) but the CSS classes aren't applied AND when it does load the SVG it loads each letter, one at a time.

Comment: Did you put the CSS classes in the logo.svg file (or reference them from the SVG file)? If not that's where you went wrong.

Comment: @RobertLongson the CSS is in the HTML file that the SVG is being included in. Are you suggesting to include it in logo.svg?

Comment: Only if you want it to work ;-)

Comment: Haha, thanks @RobertLongson, it worked. The issue I'm having now is that the SVG is very large and images embedded in it (a texture). The letters of the logo load in one at a time and the texture loads in so late that it doesn't animate. If this just because it's a large file or is there a way to optimize this? When I had the SVG directly in the HTML without <object> it wouldn't do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Embedding the CSS in the SVG file worked.

Answer (score -2):

If I'm not mistaken, the SVG code HAS to be declared inline in the HTML markup in order to be manipulated with CSS. Check out this article:

https://css-tricks.com/using-svg/

Comment: You can put the CSS in the SVG file or inject it into the SVG file at runtime using javascript. The fundamental point is that CSS is per-document.